# How to use owl-carousel in Angular2?

Tags: angularjs, angular, owl-carousel

I am new to Angular2 and was trying to convert owl-carousel in Angularjs to Angular2.

Below is the index.html file for the owl-carousel implementation:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
<script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.theme.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.transitions.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.js" />
<script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.15"></script>
<script data-require="jquery@2.1.3" data-semver="2.1.3" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<data-owl-carousel class="owl-carousel" data-options="{navigation: true, pagination: false, rewindNav : false}">
  <div owl-carousel-item="" ng-repeat="item in ::items1" class="item">
    <p>{{::item}}</p>
  </div>
</data-owl-carousel>
 <data-owl-carousel class="owl-carousel" data-options="{navigation: false, pagination: true, rewindNav : false}">
  <div owl-carousel-item="" ng-repeat="item in ::items2" class="item">
    <p>{{::item}}</p>
  </div>
</data-owl-carousel>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is the app.js file:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.items1 = [1,2,3,4,5];
$scope.items2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
}).directive("owlCarousel", function() {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: false,
    link: function (scope) {
        scope.initCarousel = function(element) {
          // provide any default options you want
            var defaultOptions = {
            };
            var customOptions = scope.$eval($(element).attr('data-options'));
            // combine the two options objects
            for(var key in customOptions) {
                defaultOptions[key] = customOptions[key];
            }
            // init carousel
            $(element).owlCarousel(defaultOptions);
        };
    }
};
}).directive('owlCarouselItem', [function() {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    transclude: false,
    link: function(scope, element) {
      // wait for the last item in the ng-repeat then call init
        if(scope.$last) {
            scope.initCarousel(element.parent());
        }
    }
};
}]);
```

This is the Angular1 implementation how to implement it for Angular2?

Comment: you can mark answer below

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Update**

**[OwlCarousel2 + Angular2.3.0](https://plnkr.co/edit/HV6MNbC3vE04P9q0QnPv?p=preview)**

```
ngOnDestroy() {
  this.$owlElement.owlCarousel('destroy');
  this.$owlElement = null;
}
```

**Old version**

Below is the app.ts file for the angular2 owl-carousel implementation:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import { OwlCarousel } from './owl-carousel.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  directives: [OwlCarousel],
  template: `
    <h2>Sample 1</h2>
    <owl-carousel [options]="{navigation: true, pagination: false, rewindNav : false}">
       <div *ngFor="#item of items1">
         <p>{{ item }}</p>
       </div>
    </owl-carousel>
    <h2>Sample 2</h2>
    <owl-carousel [options]="{navigation: false, pagination: true, rewindNav : false}">
       <div *ngFor="#item of items2">
         <p>{{ item }}</p>
       </div>
    </owl-carousel>
    <h2>Sample 3</h2>
    <owl-carousel [options]="{navigation: false, pagination: true, rewindNav : false}">
       <div *ngFor="#img of images">
         <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/{{img}}"/>
       </div>
    </owl-carousel>`
})
export class App {
  items1: array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

  items2: array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

  images: array = ['sports', 'abstract', 'people', 'transport', 'city', 'technics', 'nightlife', 'animals'];
}
```

owl-carousel.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input, ElementRef } from 'angular2/core';
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'owl-carousel';

@Component({
  selector: 'owl-carousel',
  template: `<ng-content></ng-content>`
})
export class OwlCarousel {
  @Input() options: object;

  $owlElement: any;

  defaultOptions: object = {};

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    for (var key in this.options) {
      this.defaultOptions[key] = this.options[key];
    }
    this.$owlElement = $(this.el.nativeElement).owlCarousel(this.defaultOptions);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.$owlElement.data('owlCarousel').destroy();
    this.$owlElement = null;
  }
}
```

Full example you can see in [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/jSGGRogeT8zX4a585W3T?p=preview)

**OwlCarousel2** version is here https://plnkr.co/edit/FnZVxB?p=preview

Comment: great answer! Timesaver badge!

Comment: does not show up on my rig,
if i try awl2 then even worse:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

Comment: @Ivanesses Try to add `owl-carousel` class to owl component via `HostBinding` like this https://plnkr.co/edit/FnZVxB?p=preview

Comment: Added small update on this question.
Can't wait to mark your answer.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38018460/how-to-use-owl-carousel-2-in-angular2

Comment: This line is crashing : this.$owlElement.data('owlCarousel').destroy(); Is the 'owlCarousel' internally set by the library?

Comment: @techguy2000 In 2 version you need to use `this.$owlElement.owlCarousel('destroy');` to destroy carousel. I've updated plunker

Comment: @yurzui Thanks!  Is this the same as this.$owlElement.trigger('destroy.owl.carousel')?

Comment: how do I load it with webpack instead ?

Comment: How to add it in angular-cli project

Comment: What happens if I want to add a new element to it?

Answer (score 1):

The above does not work for owl2 because the library expects the class attribute:

e.g. see this code in owl2:

```
    if (settings.responsiveClass) {
            this.$element.attr('class',
                this.$element.attr('class').replace(
     new RegExp('(' +this.options.responsiveClass + '-)\\S+\\s', 'g'), 
      '$1' + match));
```

make sure to include the class attribute in the element.

Comment: This answer should really be a comment on the other answer you are referencing. Once you [earn](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/146472) sufficient [reputation](//$SITEURL$/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](//$SITEURL$/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I thought it was important enough to risk posting as a separate post given that my reputation here is way undervalued, and i cannot yet add comments.